# Two jars with same size showing different checksum,why this happens?

Tags: java, jenkins, jar

From Jenkins build,i picked two jars from UAT and Production folders,both the sizes are same and jar comparison shows all files in the jar are same,but the checksum values are different for both the jars,can somebody help me to understand this

Comment: Maybe because they are not the same? If you are 100% sure they are the same (don't just look at the size!), it could be a salt that distorts the result.

Comment: i am 100% sure they re same,i confirmed it by using jar comparator,it shows contents of both the jars are same.due to my companies privacy policies i cannot disclose the jar comparator results.

Answer (score 4):

Timestamp differences and different file order will cause a different checksum as far as I know.